# Clarification of Newton-Raphson implementation

Tags: matlab, iteration, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, newtons-method

Could you please explain how this code works? I can understand most of it, but the `cnt` command has me confused. What does `cnt` stand for and how is it used to solve the equation?

```matlab
t=0; %% Initial estimate of t
idx=1; %% Number of iterations
iter=zeros(1,100); %% Array to store sequence of t values
func=zeros(1,100); %% Array to store sequence of f(t) values
eps=1e-6; %% Required accuracy
n_max=100; %% Number of iterations
f=1; %% f contains f(t)
while abs(f)>eps && idx<n_max

  f=-5-exp(-t)+cos(.3*pi*t)+(.1*t*t);
  dfdt=exp(-t)-(0.3*pi*sin(0.3*pi*t))+(0.2*t);

  iter(idx)=t;
  func(idx)=f;
  idx=idx+1;

  t=t-f/dfdt;
end

cnt=idx-1;
t=linspace(0,10,100);

f=zeros(1,100);
for idx=1:100
  f(idx)=-5-exp(-t(idx))+cos(.3*pi*t(idx))+(.1*t(idx)*t(idx));
end

figure, hold on;
grid on;
plot(t,f);
scatter(iter(1:cnt),func(1:cnt),'r');
title('Newton-Raphson Example','FontSize', 12)
legend('f(t)','Iterations', 'NorthWest');
xlabel('t', 'FontSize', 12);
ylabel('f(t)','FontSize', 12);
```

Comment: For future visitors, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) on Newton-Raphson method.  Also known as Newton's Method.

Answer (score 2):

`cnt`, which usually stands for "count" or "counter", is not used to *solve* anything, but to *plot* it.

If we follow the algorithm we can see that:

- Initially, `iter` and `func` are preallocated as vectors of length 100 - indicating that the algorithm is expected to converge within this number of iterations (or fewer).
- Later, when the `while` loop finishes, `cnt` keeps track of how many iterations it **actually** took to converge.
- Finally, when creating the `scatter` plot, `cnt` is used as the final index for plotting, so that we don't end up showing all the zeros that correspond to `iter(cnt+1:n_max)` and `func(cnt+1:n_max)`.